# Best Way to Automatically Publish Content of a Web Page Article online Into an Existing Template (with FTP?)

Tags: javascript, python, html

Say I have a news website with articles, I have a blank article page with everything BUT the headline, photos, and the text article itself that I would ordinarily fill in manually. Instead of filling it in, say I have the entire div class ripped from a web page already. I want to import this content directly onto the page and publish it with minimal steps.

(I hope I'm giving you the picture. Imagine I have cars fully built aside from missing engines and I want the monkeys I've hired to steal engines to not leave the engines piling up outside, but instead to also bring them inside and install them into the cars and drive them to the car dealer.) 
I will be web scraping something like a Wikipedia page on golf and putting that into my page. I don't want to have to copy, paste and click publish over and over. I want the web scraper, which I already know how to build, to go another step and do a find and replace of a certain div class on my blank page website INSTEAD of writing the data on a file on my computer's hard drive (though maybe writing on my hard drive with Python, then having JS or something read the HTML file on my hard drive THEN writing it to my web page would be a way to do it.

Are there programs that will do this? Do you know of modules that will do this through Python? Do you know of anything like this somebody wrote and put up on GitHub?

I'm not planning on ripping off news websites, but just to give a simpler example with one object... If I had the entire div class "content" from here...
http://www.zerohedge.com/news/2017-02-18/merkel-says-there-problem-euro-blames-mario-draghi
saved as an HTML file on my hard drive (which you could look at by clicking 'inspect' anywhere on the text of the main article> right clicking copy> copy as outerHTML> and pasting as an HTML in your text editor (again, something I would have done with a web scraper), how could I get this pasted into a blank 'new article' page and published on my website with the push of a button automatically? I'm fine with having to click a few buttons but not copying and pasting.

I'll be doing this (legally) with parts of web pages over and over and over again and I'm sure this can be automated in some way. I've heard financial news websites have been writing articles from data so something like what I need probably exist. I might be running the text I scrape through a basic neural net or feeding it to GANs. I think some interesting things can be made this way in case you are curious what I'm up to.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python to do this, the quickest way I feel would be to have the web crawler save it's findings to either a JSON file or SQL database that your website front-end shares access to (storing the HTML you pulled as a string of text).

If you go the JSON route, just send an AJAX request to it for the website and place it in using innerHTML on the element you're dumping the code into.

If you go the SQL route, just have a python script with the website that you can send a POST request to and have the python script pull the website data you want from the database and return it to the browser as JSON and do the same as the above.

The benefit of going straight to JSON is not having to setup connection to an SQL server and deal with the SQL query to JSON conversion step. However, the benefit of the SQL database is not having to worry about any issues writing to the JSON file if your crawler is working with multiple threads and may have write conflicts if you don't lock the file correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Does AJAX do the job instead of FTP or in conjunction with FTP? What does AJAX do that FTP can't, and why JSON format? Python wouldn't be able to pull the non public HTML off the server> insert the new HTML content into it > then save it into the public server's directory alone?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. AJAX is a built in functionality in the browser, so it it'd be used instead of FTP, but simulating the same functionality of FTP. AJAX offers the ability for JavaScript to fetch data from files in the browser, while FTP is a protocol that doesn't fit too well for client-end coding. JSON because JavaScript can read it, Python can easily convert to it, and it's very terse. Python can pull the HTML and save it to the server, I was answering how to take the HTML you have and send it to the browser.